# GraphQL for .NET - cancellation token

Tags: .net-core, graphql

is there a way to pass cancellation token in graphql endpoint?

```
public class GetAccountQuery : ObjectGraphType
{ public GetAccountQuery(IRolver resolver)
        {
            FieldAsync<UserType>(
                "GetAccount",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IdGraphType>> { Name = "userId" },
                resolve: async context => await resolver.ResolveAsync(context, pass in cancellation token ?? ));
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a subscription and canceling that? It works for Apollo, have not tried with .Net. https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/subscriptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, inject the IHttpContextAccessor into the GetAccountQuery ctor and then access the Cancellation token from the httpcontext like so:

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IResolveFieldContext` (the `context` argument in your lambda expression) has a `CancellationToken` property. You should use that.

Depending on your setup, this property will contain the appropriate token. Eg. in an APS.NET Core project, it will be set to `HttpContext.RequestAborted`.